# How to retain html tags in Fieldmanager_TextArea in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to retain HTML tags in the string. Below is my code and it strips out all the HTML tags. Could someone please help me?

```
`'field_name' => new \Fieldmanager_TextArea( [
        'label' => 'Lable Name',
        'attributes' => [
            'rows' => 4,
            'cols' => 90,
        ],
        'description' => 'Sample Text Area.',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_allowed_html',
] ),`
```

Comment: you should probably describe where exactly this piece of code is used, it is too much out of context

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Below is the right callback for the textarea. Thanks!

`'sanitize_callback' => 'wp_kses_post'`